# Alerts for Dead Letter Queue is not working as expected in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-monitoring, dead-letter

**Alerts for Dead Letter Queue is not working as expected in Azure Service Bus.**

When I Inject Dead letter messages using Azure Service Bus Explorer. It Doesn't Trigger alert mail in a way it should. I get alert email even when there is no change in the DLQ message count

Condition for alert is
If the average message in DLQ is greater than count 1, then send alert email. It should check every 5 min for period of 5 min
[Alert Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMbOx.png)

The Graph for DLQ gets dropped and back up again to same number of DLQ [Graph of the Count of DLQ messages in queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U1HS.png). So every time when there is drop in the graph it sends a email, even there is no change in the DLQ Count.

It sends two email message "Activated the DLQ" and "Deactivated DLQ"

Is there something wrong I am doing in setting up the DLQ alert or is this a bug in Microsoft DLQ alert mechanism.

Comment: "When I Inject Dead letter messages using Azure Service Bus Explorer." - what does "inject" mean? Messages can only be dead-lettered, not sent to DLQ.

Comment: @SeanFeldman  I meant I created a messages which will transferred to Dead-Letter Queue.